# How to substract a list of numbers from another list of numbers until 0 in java

Tags: java, algorithm

I have 2 lists of numbers. I need to subtract the second list from the first in a way that shows the balance until the first list equals 0.
For example

```
List A = [10,9] 
List B - [1,2,3,4,5,4]
```

I need to show

```
10-1=9
9-2=7
7-3=4
4-4=0
9-5=4
4-4=0
```

I tried

```
 for (int a : List A){
        do {
            for (int b : List B){
                a = -b
            }
        } while (a >= 0)
    }
```

I don't think the logic is sound enough and could use a few pointers.

Comment: `int i = 0; for (int a : A) while (a > 0) System.out.println(a + "-" + B[i] + "=" + (a -= B[i++]));`

Comment: Is there a guarantee the sum of numbers in one list will be equal to the sum of numbers in the other list?

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer: even if there is such a guarantee, the problem is equivalent to the knapsack problem, so it's NP complete. It certainly does not have a simple greedy solution. (Unless you're allowed to split a value in List B between two or more values in List A.)

Comment: @rici I also thought this was a hard problem until I saw the first comment. Maybe the exercise really is that trivial, i.e. the prefix subarray of B will always add to the first element of A. In other words, maybe this is an "Introduction to Coding" homework problem, and not a coding contest question.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer: I think I understood your question. But it's not sufficient for the sums to be equal. Consider A={11, 9}, B={2, 4, 6, 8}. No solution even though both sum to 20. Or change A to {10, 10}. Now there's a solution, but the greedy algorithm won't find it; you need an algorithm which can backtrack.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your logic more simpler with early breaks if `a` becomes `0` before subtracting from all elements in `B`. Also, it looks like you wish to subtract them in a circular manner until `a` becomes `0`.

**Snippet:**

```
for(int a : A){
    int ptr = 0;
    while(a > 0){
        System.out.println(a + " - " + B.get(ptr) + " = " + (a - B.get(ptr)));
        a -= B.get(ptr);
        ptr = (ptr + 1) % B.size();
    }
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/java/3yxg29d3v)

**Note:** Not every element subtraction leads to the beautiful 0, but that is how your array is kept in the first place.

Also, there is no other optimized way looking at your current requirements since you will have to loop through each one and show the subtraction steps.

Comment: OOoooo. I thought it was some obscure math thing, but that makes way more sense.